# How to write and save a log file when executing a method (setting the level through application properties)

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, logback

I am new to Springboot and I need help, I want to execute a method that saves a log file with the value of a variable, I inserted the parameters in my logback.xml but the log is generated when I run the application, and is generated in white.
Another thing, I defined my log level through environment variables, how do I use this variable that is already in my application properties ??
Thank you very much

```
<configuration>
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${user.home}/bws.log</file>
    <append>false</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%-5relative %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>

    </encoder>
</appender>

<root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

Application properties
    bws.log.level=${BWS_LOG_LEVEL}

Log Class
    @Component
public class Logs {
private static String myLevelLog;

```
@Value("${bws.log.level}")
public void setLevel(String lv){
    myLevelLog=lv;
}

private static final Logger logger
        = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logs.class);

public static void totalAlunos(int al){
    logger.debug("Total de alunos no banco de dados:"+ al, Logs.class.getSimpleName());
    // This is what I need to write to the log file, but getting the level I set up through my environment variables
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can add filter to your appender in logback xml file.

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
     <level>${BWS_LOG_LEVEL}</level>
</filter>
```

This will ensure that logback will only save messages with `${BWS_LOG_LEVEL}` level .

```
<filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
     <level>${BWS_LOG_LEVEL}</level>
</filter>
```

In comparasion to `LevelFilter`, `ThresholdFilter` will fire on level
 equal or above the specified `${BWS_LOG_LEVEL}`

**UPDATED**

I noticed that you didn't activate your appender, try something like

```
<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</root>
```

This will pass logs from all packages to `STDOUT` and `FILE` appenders. If you want to set appender only for specific package, just add logger:

```
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
<logger name="your.package.here.Logs" level="off" additivity="false">
  <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
</logger>
```

This will pass all logs thought the `STDOUT`, and additionally all logs from package/class `your.package.here.Logs` will be passed to `FILE` appender.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I write to the file? And as I write only when I run the method, the way I'm doing it is generating a blank file every time I run the application ...

Comment: See additional @Manzini

Comment: `code`  public static void totalAlunos(int al){
        logger.debug("Total de alunos no banco de dados:"+ al, Logs.class.getSimpleName());
        // This is what I need to write to the log file, but getting the level I set up through my environment variables
    }`code`

Thanks, but how do I write to the file executing a method? my log file is blank

Comment: I do not understand you. Do you want to configure the log level 
 of this line dynamically in your code?

Comment: no, let's forget the level for now, I need that when executing this method, write in the file the number of students (variable al)
public static void totalAlunos(int al){
logger //"número de alunos no database"+al

Comment: What level do you set in `${BWS_LOG_LEVEL}`?  Did you try to add appender to the `<root>` or `<logger>`? Do you use `Slf4j`? Why do use pass `Logs.class.getSimpleName()` as a second argument to logger?

Comment: $ {BWS LOG LEVEL} - The value of this in my environment variables is DEBUG, and so it's in my application properties - bws.log.level = $ {BWS_LOG_LEVEL} and yes I'm using Slf4j

Comment: Why do use pass Logs.class.getSimpleName() as a second argument to logger? -----
just used it because I saw it like this in an example, I'm totally lost, please what is the correct way to do this?